# find line number of last occurance of pattern before specific line number

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a large file of events like so:

```
<event>
...
...multiple lines describing the event
...
</event>
<event>
...
... 
<event>
```

When a error occurs I get the line number where the error has occurred which always ends off being somewhere within the event tags. I want to split the file on events processed before the error occurred and from the error onwards. I know that I can do the split using

```
csplit -k filename line_number_to_split_on
```

What I need to do is find the line number of the previous event tag to the error line. 
The files are quite large. For example I has an error listed on line 1007425 and from looking at the file the event tag was on line 1007397. I'd like a way to do this in shell script. Any ideas?

Comment: Need more information about the input file and information that you need as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about performance on large files but it works.

```
#!/bin/sh
total=$(cat EVENTFILE |wc -l)
error=$1 ### Line number where error occurred
from=$((total-error))
num=$(tac EVENTFILE|awk '/<event>/{print NR}'|while read n; do
    echo ${n};
    if test ${n} -ge ${from}; then
        break;
    fi;
    done|tail -1)
echo $((total-num+1))
```

Test data.

```
 1  <event>
 2  .
 3  .
 4  .
 5  </event>
 6  <event>
 7  ..
 8  ..
 9  ..
10  </event>
11  <event>
12  ...
13  ...
14  ...
15  </event>
```

Output

```
foo@ell:/tmp/test$ ./test.sh 3
1
foo@ell:/tmp/test$ ./test.sh 8
6
foo@ell:/tmp/test$ ./test.sh 14
11
```

Comment: didn't work. It printed out the line number of the last line in the file

Comment: my bad. it worked. The opening event tag did not close immediately so all I had to do was to change "<event>" in the awk to "<event " and it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: This seems overly complicated.  Using tac is a good idea, though.  If the error occurred on line 345, you can simply do: sed 345q input | tac | sed -n '/<event>/{p; q;}'

Answer (score 2):

Given $LINE as the line number where the error occurs, and $FILE as the input file, you can do:

```
$ nl -ba $FILE | sed -n -e '/<event>/p' -e ${LINE}q | tail -1
```

(You can use the '=' operator in sed to get line numbers instead of nl, but I like nl better and = is not very portable.  Also, it inserts additional newlines that are a bit of a pain.)

As an alternative to piping to tail, you could do:

```
$ nl -ba $FILE | sed -n -e '/<event>/h' -e$LINE'{x; p; q;}'
```

Comment: clever. linux has so many commands that even experienced users don't know about. I only fairly recently heard of tac and hadn't heard of nl until now. Never saw = used in sed. I see from the man pages that it can though. Thx

Comment: I would like to point out if you replace `/<event>/p` with `/<event>/=` on your first solution, you will achieve the line number only and not the line number + event tag. The `=` command is printed independently of the pattern space (which is suppressed by `-n` anyway). As to portability, I believe it has been part of the spec for many years.

Answer (score 1):

Your input looks like XML. The best way to do it would be to use an XML parser. Parsing XML by hand is not so much fun. Depending on the XML-Parser the start line numbers are part of the element metadata. (For example for SAX theres the [Locator](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/Locator.html).)

**Update:**

It thought that using the right tool is a good idea. If you can't use a XML parser you have to write your own for your XML subset. You should start by looking at the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) and see which features you actually need. It would remove a lot of complexity if you did not have to support recursion, XML entities and XML CDATA. After you got this information your question can be answered.

Comment: i would prefer not to use something not on a vanilla linux machine as this is deployed on sites that don't want any software other than what comes with basic linux installed on their machines